# Editing and saving old crystal report in their old format

Tags: crystal-reports

I have an old crystal report file. Version 10.2 to be more specific. I have an application that uses this report and I don't have access to modify this application. However, I have to edit this report and save it in the same format and same version so that the application may use it. However when I use the tools available to edit the crystal report files, I can only save it as the newest version.

Are there any crystal report editors that allows me to edit and save the file as version 10.2?

Comment: This says not possible: http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/Forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=104 I find it hard to believe that's the case, though. Best of luck to you.

Comment: You may have to suck it up and find a copy of Crystal 10.2. I have never had any luck making different file versions work with different app versions.